# why interface comes like eth1@if11 in network namespace?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, docker

I attached an end of the Veth with separate network namespace. But I noticed that "@if11" is automatically added with my created Veth. Can anyone please explain it what is this?

[image: Separate network namespace interfaces]

Answer (score 0):

`if11` means that the other end of the `veth` pair has the internal **I**nter**F**ace number 11, but as it isn't present in this network namespace, it has no name. So this name is used as a replacement.

If you create a veth pair in a single namespace (or the main namespace), you'll see `name1@name2` instead.